# jsPDF is not defined when saving div to PDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf-generation, jspdf, referenceerror

I'm trying to save div element with specific id using jsPDF but getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined`. Tried bunch of different ways to fix this issue including all available solutions on stackoverflow and none of them worked.

Here is how the div element looks like (it's a table that autofills depending on user choices, I removed most of options to reduce number of lines for this example). Below is a quick snippet to give an idea what's going on. It still says that jsPDF not deifned:

```js
$('#savePDF').click(function() {
  var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
        source = $('#yourSummary');
        specialElementHandlers = {
            '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
                return true
            }
        };
        margins = {
            top: 80,
            bottom: 60,
            left: 40,
            width: 522
        };
        pdf.fromHTML(
            source,
            margins.left,
            margins.top, {
                'width': margins.width,
                'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
            },

            function (dispose) {
                pdf.save('your-summary.pdf');
            }, margins
        );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
<div id="yourSummary" class="modal-body">
  <table id="yourExterior" class="table table-hover">
  <h5>Exterior</h5>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <th scope="row">Body colour</th>
      <td id="sumBC"></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<button class="btn-primary" id="savePDF">Save configuration as PDF</button>
```

But once I push the button in browser I have following errors:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (main.js:34)
at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2)
at HTMLButtonElement.v.handle (jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2)
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix this issue?

Comment: It might help to build a working example here, ideally using a [stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). That might give us a better idea of what's going wrong.

Comment: @showdev thanks for suggestion, just updated the question with the snippet and it gives the same error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the previous version
`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>`

The version 2.0.0 is very different.
For an example, instead of the method "jsPDF" you will use jspdf.jsPDF, but you will see new errors.

Comment: Just for reference: [jsPDF release 2.0](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/releases).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, as this information should be in their documentation.